# Count based on calculation with no absolute range using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet connected to a txt file, with automatic refresh. I manage to get the data into the sheet. Below is an example of two rows:

```
1367945797  0,000   MainThread  ---
1367945798  0,709   MainThread  200
```

The first column contains a unix timestamp, which Excel doesn't understand as a date/time info. I know I can convert the timestamp using the following formula:

```
=(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970;1;1)
```

The second column contains a response time in ms.

**The goal:**
I want to count the number of rows where the time is:

```
Hour(formula_above) equals 16
```

, and calculate the average response time this hour

I'm trying to create a graph that shows the average response time for every hour in a day (1-24 hours).

It's important to note that I don't have an absolute range as new data is coming into the my data sheet.

I tried to use CountIF() but it doesn't look like it can calculate, and use the calculated value as if statement.

Any other ways of dealing with this issue?

Is there a simple function which itterates through the range (e.g: Sheet1!A:A) and gives me the value in each iteration, where I can return a value/boolean per iteration, and use countif or other formulas to do some magic stuff?

Comment: Can you use a pivot table?

Comment: I think you might be able to use an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original timestamp is in column A you can use this array formula to average column B based on Hour 16 of column A

`=AVERAGE(IF(HOUR(A:A/86400)=16;B:B))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or you can pull the hour out using a helper column, e.g. in C2 copied down

`=HOUR(A2/86400)`

Then you can use `AVERAGEIF` like this

`=AVERAGEIF(C:C;16;B:B)`

Comment: This seems to do the trick, Barry. But when I try to add an AND operator, I only get 0 (0.00000000000). I know for a fact that a row contains 15 in column B, and the string "search" in column E, and has a value above 0.
    =AVERAGE(IF(AND(Data!B:B=15;Data!E:E="search");Data!C:C))

Comment: I also need to add that I now get the Hour value straight out in my file. That's why I don't have the calculation anymore.

Comment: You can't use AND in that way, for an array formula you need `=AVERAGE(IF((Data!B:B=15)*(Data!E:E="search");Data!C:C))` but AVERAGEIFS is better, i.e. `=AVERAGEIFS(Data!C:C;Data!B:B;15;Data!E:E;"search")`

Comment: It's worth to note that your /86400 is wrong if you want to get todays date. You have to add the date from 01.01.1970. Just for information if anyone wondered

Comment: @smarty......but my suggested formula is only to extract the `HOUR` of the day, adding days won't change that so it's not necessary.....e.g. =HOUR(x/86400) is always equal to HOUR(x/86400+y) if y is an integer (and a date in excel is an integer)